# How can I discover the methods available to me in an unmanaged DLL

Tags: windows, dllimport

When doing a dll import like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SwapMouseButton(bool fSwap);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SwapMouseButton(false);
    }
```

How would one go about knowing that there is a method called SwapMouseButton within `user32.dll` that takes a bool parameter and returns a bool value?

Obviously there is no intellisense to save the day. So is there a website that lists this all out, or a program that I can type user32.dll into that will discover it for me?

Comment: You don't search the DLLs. You search MSDN for the functions you need, and then link to the appropriate .h .lib and .dll

Comment: @David, looks like MSDN has a cool quick reference page now. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for the link. I hadn't seen that page; it's a handy reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User32.dll' is part of the Windows API itself, and the API is documented at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com). The typical way to find things there is to decide what you're trying to do, and then search for that topic.

There's no way to find the parameters for an unmanaged DLL's functions. You can find the name of the functions (usually) with `depends.exe` (part of VS), or with [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). This won't give you the parameters, though; those have to be obtained from the documentation for the library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use depends.exe which comes with Visual Studio. You can load in a dll and it will show you all the functions inside, as well as the dependencies.

You can also try Dumpbin: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c